# Require function not recognized after upgrade from node 12 to 14

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, node-modules

I upgraded my node version from 12 to 14.5.0 (I needed to use es6 classes and syntax and I found that node 14 supports it) using this [link](https://medium.com/codespace69/upgrading-node-js-to-latest-version-how-to-update-node-to-any-version-using-npm-47c97d5ffe30)
But when I try to run my node js app after the update it shows this :

```
[nodemon] 2.0.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js command`

const path = require("path");
             ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at file:///./NodeJsClient/app.js:1:14
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:140:23)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:162:24)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Do I need to update nodemon or npm ? How do I fix this?
My npm verion is 6.14.5

Comment: It looks like node is using an ESM module loader (which loads new type modules) and `require()` is not defined in an ESM module.  If the problem is coming from app.js and you are you are running node app.js to start your app, then it must be interpreted as an ESM module because you have  directive in your package.json file that tells nodejs to load your main file as an ESM module.  You would need to change that.  Show us your package.json file.

Comment: And, FYI you could have used ES6 classes and other ES6 syntax just fine in node v12, though that is completely unrelated to your current issue.

Comment: Do you have `"type": "module"` in your package.json file?  If so, change that line to `"type": "commonjs"`.

Comment: I don't understand - Use both what?

Comment: When you say ES6, what exactly do you mean?  ES6 syntax has been available in nodejs for a long time (several years).

Comment: You can use `import` in an ESM module and `require()` in a commonjs module.  You don't mix the two in the same module.  Your current app.js file is a commonjs module.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes it works now. I replaced "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs". Thanks . About using es6 though , I searched a lot on the internet but couldn't find an example. I wanted to use the es6 syntax without using babel.

Comment: You can rewrite your app.js file to be an ESM module if you want.  ESM modules are still a bit new in nodejs and compatibility between module types can be tricky to use right now so that you can use both module types in the same nodejs project.  It can be done, but there are challenges to figure out.

Comment: @jfriend00 I thought ES6 syntax wasn't natively supported in node unless using a transpiler like babel am I wrong ?

Comment: @Sven.hig I thought that too. I don't exactly remember/have the exact link but I read here on SO that node version 14 supports it without a transpiler

Comment: @HackleSaw Yes that's what I thought as well

Comment: node 14 does support ESM modules natively if you configure your project correctly and are indeed loading an ESM module file.  This question was attempting to load a CommonJS module as an ESM module.  You can't do that.  An ESM file cannot use `require()`.  It must use the newer `import` syntax.  Likewise a CommonJS file cannot use `import` - it must use `require()`.  And files that export things have to the exports differently in CommonJS vs. ESM modules.  Your app.js file is a CommonJS module (that's how you've written it) so it can't be loaded as an ESM module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nodejs is attempting to load your app.js file as an ESM module file, but it isn't an ESM module file - it's a CommonJS module file.  There is no `require()` in an ESM module file which is why you get the error.

Since your file is a CommonJS module, it seem likely that apparently have some directive that is telling node to try to load your file as an ESM module.  The most likely place that would be is in your package.json file where you should make sure you have:

```
type: "commonjs"
```

not

```
type: "module"
```